# Java Socket Programming

Tags: java

How do the server sockets and the sockets are bind in Java

Comment: Much like in C. See [Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), et al.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471342/java-socket-programming

Comment: Network programming is best learned via an introductory text, rather than hoping someone will come along with an excellent answer. If you just want to know how to drive _Java_, [this wikipedia page on Nio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) may be useful. If you're completely new to sockets programming, [TCP/IP Illustrated Vol 1](http://www.powells.com/biblio/65-9780201633467-1) is an excellent starting point. (But old. Ignore all `T/TCP` TCP-transactions references. It never materialized. Also, I can't recall if it ever mentioned IPv6, but I can't imagine it covered it in enough depth.)

Comment: Google is a better place to ask such questions. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+do+the+server+sockets+and+the+sockets+are+bind+in+Java over 17 million results.

Comment: Check out this tutorial, it is easy and compact: http://hippieitgeek.blogspot.se/2012/12/multi-threaded-network-programming-in.html

Answer (score 2):

Please. There are about a gazillion sources on the Internet that show how to work with sockets. Start by looking at the Documentation for [`Socket`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) and [`ServerSocket`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html). If this doesn't help you have to get more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but if you want to do Java socket programming, there is a decent tutorial and explanation of sockets in Java to be found at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/